# Does Autopilot make planes safer?

Tags: safety, autopilot

Statistically, are planes with advanced autopilot functionality less likely to be involved in fatal crashes? Answer only with actual statistics, not your personal opinion.

Comment: This is a very broad question to which there exists no single correct answer. I suggest you have a read here: https://www.eurocontrol.int/sites/default/files/publication/Hindsight/Hindsight-20.pdf

Comment: @J.Hougaard: Can you provide an overall idea of why the number of incidents/accidents could increase with some automation equipment? It seems the bottom line is positive, as automation continues to be implemented, and the number of accidents continues to decrease. Perhaps this is only a matter of appropriate training to take over automation when it fails?

Comment: @mins You can *train* for taking over when automation fails, but staying proficient will be nearly impossible because you only get a fraction of the hands on experience you would if you were doing everything manually. Case in point: AF447

Comment: @J.Hougaard, agreed. I was only emphasizing that increasing safety doesn't mean removing all accidents, nor preventing accidents for new causes created by automation, just the number of cases decreases. Since the car safety belt has been mandatory, people likely died because of the belt, perhaps drowned in water,  but driving with a belt is still safer overall. AF447 is indeed one of these cases.

Comment: The answer is definitively yes if well-understood and used properly.

Comment: Voting to re-open. It's an interestimg question: automation helps flight economics, does it also improve safety. Perhaps the community knows of a study that indicates this.

Comment: You might want to check out this [NASA report](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19870012488.pdf) on the effects of autopilot use in single pilot IFR.

Comment: The autopilot is as safe as we programmed it to be. The more factors the autopilot can factor in the safer it will be. But I think the real difference between safety occurs when something abnormal happens to the aircraft like broken control wires making the controls very unpredictable. A human can understand this or at least try. To make a computer capable of this is very very hard. In daily operation a computer does not make mistakes if properly programmed. A human is susceptible to skip steps by mistake in routine work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using e.g. [Boeing's annual commercial aviation safety statistics](http://www.boeing.com/resources/boeingdotcom/company/about_bca/pdf/statsum.pdf), one can essentially show that with each new aircraft generation, the accident rate reduces. This answers your question about statistic involvement, but doesn't really confirm a causal relationship, since it's not only automation but e.g. also human machine interface (flight deck) design and system architecture that improves. However, I would assume there are quite probably at least some safety improvements due to automation in there. One would need to go about analysing the accident factors to prove this.

As an interesting aside touching on this topic, a former colleague of mine flying commercial jets recently offered his first-hand view on different aircraft automation levels in [his blog](https://mmsba.wordpress.com/2017/05/15/airbus-or-boeing-part-2-5/).

While not a comprehensive answer as such, I hope the links allow you to pursue this a bit further.